# Python DLL import error, module not found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dll

I am trying to run a script **python-3.7.7.amd64** via **pycharms-2020.1 x64** on a Intel i7 PC.

I downloaded the *Winpython64-3.7.7.0* application, run it and copied the files to `C:\Program Files`. 
When I select the interpreter the import package that is causing the problem (pandas) is included and can been found in site-packages.

The script has an import statement for pandas;

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas import ExcelWriter
```

and the error message is;

```
"C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\python.exe" 
    C:/Users/USER/Documents/Python_Code/Python3.6/Smartcharge_Data/Mean_Smartpings/Mean_Smart_Excel_v4.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File 
 "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Python_Code/Python3.6/Smartcharge_Data/Mean_Smartpings/Mean_Smart_Excel_v4.py", 
  line 9, in <module>
        import pandas as pd
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 
    55, in <module>
        from pandas.core.api import (
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 
   29, in <module>
        from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
        from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 
   124, in <module>
        from pandas.core.series import Series
       File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", 
   line 4572, in <module>
        Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", 
   line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
        from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
      File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", 
   line 5, in <module>
        import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried adding the file path for the DLLs 
( i.e. C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\DLLs)
onto the Path in User Variables and restarting but this does not work.

I have not included the entire Python script as it works perfectly well with python-3.7.1-amd64 and pycharms-20183.3.5 x64 so I don't think the script is the problem.

If it try to install pandas via pip it says that this requirement is already satisfied.

If I uninstall pandas then the error message is much shorter as shown in the attached image.
[image: Short error code, no module found]

Running a simple script that uses pandas;

```
dict = {"country": ["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
        "capital": ["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Dehli", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
        "area": [8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
       "population": [200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }

import pandas as pd

brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)

print(brics)
```

Using the IDLE(Python GUI) works fine.

The method of installing Python has worked successfully on several other machines.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've asked my work colleagues but to no avail.

Comment: a quick google shows that this might be an issue with a missing c redist, check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32857#issuecomment-615510956) github issue for more info

Comment: Please add error messages as text, instead of relying on linked screenshots.

Comment: Added format to code section and error messages. 
Tried to improved readability as well, with some formatting and newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nullman for your comment, I've now solved the issue. I stalled a vc_redist_x64.exe, for here;

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

as suggested at the bottom of this page;

https://winpython.github.io/

Thanks